# how to load stylesheets when using twig

Tags: php, html, css, twig

I have a file loginpage.php in a folder called "backend". The file loginpage.php renders a file called loginpage.html which is in a folder called templates. Inside my html file I have linked a stylesheet. However, when I run loginpage.php it echo's the html file but it is trying to find the stylesheet in the folder "backend" instead of looking in "templates".

So inside my html file I have:

```
<link href="loginpage.css " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Since loginpage.html and loginpage.css are in the same folder

Then my loginpage.php file is:

```
require_once '../../../autoload.php';

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../../templates');

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('loginpage.html', array('error' => $error));
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Twig does not "load" the css, it is the html which loads it when the page it displayed

Html just now that an url `/backend/loginpage.php` try to load the css `loginpage.css`

Without knowing your architecture it's hard to tell exactly, but you could try to `<link href="/backend/template/loginpage.css "`